# Trigonometric double identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Prove the following trigonometric identity:
$$(\sec (x) - 1)(\sec (x) + 1)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2 (x)}$$

Comment: Please clarify you question. $(\sec^2 x - 1)^2 = -1$?

Comment: (secx-1)(secx +1)

Comment: There is nice button named "edit". Use it! ;) And read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And what is RHS?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you provide more details? What have you tried yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Where is your difficulty ?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the brackets on the left side of the equation gives us\begin{equation*}
(\sec(x)-1)(\sec(x)+1)=\sec^2(x)-1=\tan^2(x)+1-1=\tan^2(x)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}
\end{equation*}
using $\tan(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and $1+\tan^2(x)=\sec^2(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

the right-hand side is given by $$\frac{\sin(x)^2}{-\cos(x)^2}=-1$$ and the left-hand side is $$\tan(x)^4$$ therefore your equation is wrong.

Comment: I find $\big(\sec(\pi/17)-1\big)\big(\sec(\pi/17)+1\big) = \frac{\sin^2(\pi/17)}{\cos^2(\pi/17)}$. Are you sure about your answer?

Comment: which answer do you mean?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, it's answer to initial question, which have been edited by OP many times

Comment: @MichaelGaluza: Ah, ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $$k=(\sec x-1)(\sec x+1)=\sec^2 x - 1 =\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}-1$$

Then

$$k\cos^2=1-\cos^2 x=\sin^2x\\ \Leftrightarrow k=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$$